# Return value from javascript object literel

Tags: javascript

I have two file a.js and b.js, I need to return value from a.js. This is the program which I wrote, please correct it thanks!

a.js

```
var a = (function(){
   var some = function(aa) {
        aa + 10;
   }
   var init = function(aa) {
      some(aa);
   }
   return {
       init : init
   }
})();
```

b.js

```
console.log(a.init(5));
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? are you using nodejs, a html or ...? what doesn't work? what should be corrected?

Comment: Assigning a self-invoking anonymous function to a variable? Why?

Comment: I'm getting undefined when i log the result.

Comment: @kinduser I need to acces another file thats why

Comment: You need to return something in your `some` function. change it to `return aa + 10`. also your `init` function, to `return some( aa )`

Comment: @mrReiha I tried `return aa + 10` but again undefined

Comment: @Rijo comment updated, your `init` function need to be updated as well.

Comment: @mrReiha so i need to write return some() on init function as well?

Comment: Yeah, check my answer down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a chain. three functions are calling here:

1. call init from *b.js*: `a.init( 5 )`
2. call init from *a.js*: `init = function( aa ) { ... }`
3. call some from *a.js*: `some = function( aa ) { ... }`

every function return undefined by default, so if u want to pass your calculated value through all of this, you need to return it in every function.

**new a.js**

```
var a = (function(){

    var some = function(aa) {
        return aa + 10;
    }

    var init = function(aa) {
       return some(aa);
    }

    return {
        init : init
    }

})();
```

now call your *b.js* file, and it will work as expected.

*Update:*

if you would like to get rid of those `return` values, you can use [arrow-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like this:

```
var a = (function(){

    var some = aa => aa + 10;

    var init = aa => some(aa);

    return {
        init : init
    }

})();
```

they will return calculated value by default ( instead of undefined ).

Comment: why I want to write three return, is there is a any short cut?

Comment: Only if you use ES6 arrow function syntax

Comment: @enf0rcer how to write short cut in es6?

Comment: @Rijo Actually, there is. but you need to use ES6 ( a.k.a. JS2 ) syntax. check updated answer.

Comment: I see @mrReiha already updated his answer. In the above example you can actually get rid of the entire init function. just use some function directly. That will save you some extra code. No need create a wrapper function for that as you only communicate via a.init method.